# Restricting Verilog parameters

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga, xilinx

I am writing a simple Verilog module, that needs to have restrictions on its parameter values. By that I mean only certain values are allowed to be assigned to a generic parameter. I know this could be done in VHDL, is there an equivalent or a workaround in Verilog? I am asking this question because the Xilinx compiler seems to see a corner case value that would never occur if my parameter was in a range.

I have tried checking my parameter in an initial block and doing a $fatal if it is out of the permitted range. That seems to be a very dirty solution...

Comment: Yes the code works, but I get a linting violation, which is what I said in a paragraph above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use SystemVerilog, which Vivado supports, this is easy using a generate-if block.

```
module top;
  dut #(1) u1 ();
endmodule
  
module dut;
  parameter p;
  if (!( p inside {[2:3]}) ) $fatal("sorry");
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks, I know it does I am just trying to keep my code Verilog only... So I guess there is no clean way to do that in Verilog?

Comment: Using `$fatal` is SystemVerilog already. Why not take full advantage of it?